# Save data in Julia

Tags: save, julia, load

Is there a standard way to easily just save any kind of data in Julia. This time I have a tuple with two arrays in it that I want to use again later. Something like this.

```
a = [1,2,34]
b = [1,2,3,4,5]

save((a,b), "ab")
a, b = load("ab")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [JLD2.jl](https://juliaio.github.io/JLD2.jl/stable/) to save and load arbitrary Julia objects. This is more likely to work for long term storage across different Julia versions than the [Serialization](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Serialization/) standard library.

```
using JLD2

x = (1, "a")
save_object("mytuple.jld2", x)
```

```
julia> load_object("mytuple.jld2")
(1, "a")
```

For additional functionality, check out the [docs](https://juliaio.github.io/JLD2.jl/stable/).

Answer (score 5):

There are many scenarios depending on how long you want to store the data

1. Serialization (this is perfect for short time periods, for longer periods where packages update their internal data structures you might have problem reading the file)

```
julia> using Serialization

julia> serialize("file.dat",a)
24

julia> deserialize("file.dat")
3-element Vector{Int64}:
  1
  2
 34
```

2. Delimited files (note that additional processing of output might be needed)

```
julia> using DelimitedFiles

julia> writedlm("file.csv", a)

julia> readdlm("file.csv", '\t' ,Int)
3×1 Matrix{Int64}:
  1
  2
 34
```

3. JSON (great for long term)

```
julia> using JSON3

julia> JSON3.write("file.json",a)
"file.json"

julia> open("file.json") do f; JSON3.read(f,Vector{Int}); end
3-element Vector{Int64}:
  1
  2
 34
```

Other worth mentioning libraries (depending on data format) include `CSV.jl` for saving data frames and `BSON.jl` for binary JSON files.